# css class '.when' shows error on netbeans IDE

Tags: css, netbeans-8

I am using netbeans 8.0.2 for coding. In css, I have used a class name 'when' and that class is showing error in editor. But it works in browser. Anybody have some idea?

[image]

Comment: @eisbehr sounds like an answer rather than a comment :)

Comment: Okay, I did. ;) @Rawrplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your IDE expects that `when` is a function of `less`, an then your syntax would be wrong. If you don't use `less`, or everything works just fine for you, ignore the warning and/or change the inspection settings.

If you use `less`, here are some examples of using `when`:

- http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-guarded-namespaces
- http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-loops-feature
- http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixin-guards-feature
- http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature
- http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature-property-variable-accessors

Comment: Ok, but I still confused why a file with '.css' extension showing error of '.less' file?

Comment: I think because of your IDE settings. In every IDE there are inspection settings. Maybe something is wrong. If you don't use `less`, disable the inspection completely if possible. @ponspurushothaman

Answer (score 1):

You can help to improve NetBeans by reporting similar issues in their bug tracking system. I have already reported this problem here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1216